# Why the env_logger doesn't work in my cli program

Tags: rust

In `Cargo.toml`, I write this:

```
log = "0.4.0"
env_logger = "0.8.4"
```

In my test code, I write this:

```rust
use log::{info, warn};

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    info!("starting up");
    warn!("oops, nothing done");
}
```

And then I set the env like this:

```
$ env | grep RUST
RUST_LOG=output_log=info
```

Every thing was done, and the test code worked well:

```
$ cargo run --bin output-log
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `target/debug/output-log`
[2021-11-06T04:05:42Z INFO  output_log] starting up
[2021-11-06T04:05:42Z WARN  output_log] oops, nothing done
```

But When I did this in my program:

```
use log::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Write};
use std::path::PathBuf;
...

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut stdout = BufWriter::new(stdout);

    env_logger::init();
    info!("This is info");
    warn!("This is warn");
    error!("This is error");
...
// write something to the stdout and flush
...
    Ok(())
}
```

Then, the env_logger didn't print any message to the terminal as before

Why this happens and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
export RUST_LOG=`executable_name`=`log_level`,...
```

So I should write

```
export RUST_LOG=grrs=info
```

Comment: Or you could simply do RUST_LOG=info ... that way if you have any libraries that have logs in them they will spit them out too. Also you may want to look at the tracing crate which is a bit more complex but a lot more powerful and is a drop in replacement for log